# Copy WPF Web Application

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF XBAP application, that i run using visual studio. Everything works fine. Now i want to send it to another person, this person has a laptop and i want him to run it directly from his laptop.
I sent him the content of the bin/debug folder, when he opens the xbap file, he gets a message "downloading..." and then an error, something about a .exe.config.deploy and .exe.deploy files are not found (there are in fact not found in the debug folder).
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could just deploy the application, and send it, or just send it as VS project, if he has VS installed.

Comment: i dont wanna send him the source code, just the xbap exe and dll.
i can't deploy it for him as we are not on the same network.